# put lists at the same length

Tags: r, list, nested-lists

I'm trying to make a loop whose doing an lm equations on a nested lists of list. but my lists are not the same length, and so my equation isn't working
I want to drop the lines where there's is NA or Zero, and the corresponding line in the lists.

what I have :

```
nested_list
[[1]]
[1] x    double(1234)
    y    double(4321)
```

what I want :

```
nested_list
[[1]]
[1] x    double(1234)
    y    double(1234)
```

and that my beginning of code:

```
pairs <- list()
n <- 1;
for(i in 1:length(xdata)) {
  for(j in 1:length(ydata)) {
    pairs[[n]] <- c(xdata[i], ydata[j])

   pairs[[n]]<-lapply( pairs[[n]], function(x) x[!is.na(x)])  
    
    n <- n + 1;
  }
}
```

the only way i made this work is with a dataframe but it's not working with my loop after.
And for the lists i've tried a lot of combinations(intersect, merge,rbind) but none worked...
if you have any ideas how to make this work, thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the code used to reach what you have?

Answer (score 0):

i finally found something. I transform my list in dataframe, drop the NA and zero and transform it again in list

```
pairs <- list()
n <- 1;
for(i in 1:length(xdata)) {
  for(j in 1:length(ydata)) {
    pairs[[n]] <- data.frame(xdata[i], ydata[j]);
    
    pairs[[n]][pairs[[n]]== 0.00]<- NA
    
    pairs[[n]]<- pairs[[n]][!is.na(pairs[[n]][1]),]
    pairs[[n]]<- pairs[[n]][!is.na(pairs[[n]][2]),] 

   pairs[[n]]<- c(pairs[[n]][1],pairs[[n]][2])
    n <- n + 1;
  }
}
```